# How to upload photo from camera to QuickBlox using phonegap/cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, quickblox, phonegap-cli

I'm using JavaScript SDK of QuickBlox for chatting purpose. And I need to upload photo from camera to update profile pic.
**Some information related to my application is as below:**
I'm developing Hybrid app using Cordova CLI(6.0.0). This is not my first app.

I'm using code below to upload an image. It is working fine with the input type file tag on browser, but I don't know how to upload file from camera to Quickblox. So please guide me.

```
QB.content.createAndUpload({file: file, type: file.type, size: file.size, 'public': true}, function(err, blob) {
    console.log(blob);
    if (blob) {
        QB.users.update(self.id, {blob_id: blob.id}, function(err, user) {
            if (user) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(user)); // success
            } else {
                alert("Error:update");       // error
            }
        });
    } else {
        // error
        alert("Error:upload");
    }
});
```

Comment: This is not a Cordova or Phonegap issue.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 Thanks for your reply,I just want a solution for above functionality.

Comment: In review of the documentation for QuickBlox AND since this is your first post, please **answer the following questions in your post**. I might have an answer for you. Is this your first hybrid App? Are you using the Desktop App? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 Your post is awesome ,Thanks for sharing it. I've updated information in my post.Please review it.

Comment: Is this your **first** hybrid App? Are you using the *Desktop App*?

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 No I have already worked on approximately 10  cordova apps ,But Integrating Quick blox chat first time I'm not using Desktop app.Now not able to upload image in this using QuickBlox JavaScript SDK,This code in working fine with input type file on desktop browser,But I want to upload image from the camera.

Comment: Okay. Good. You need to implement the *whitelist* plugin. I will post the full answer in a bit. In addition, you should know that *Phongap Build* is a cloud-based build tool by Adobe/Phonegap. If you are using CLI, you are not using *Phongap Build*. I have fixed your tags.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 I really appreciate your quick response,my main concern is that how to get file object that is same as Input type file to pass in  file parameter in the above example .I have already added white list plugin in the project,Yes Jesse I'm using only CLI not phonegap build

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 I also tried their Rest api to upload content using cordova file transfer api ,It is throwing error code 1 error:http://quickblox.com/developers/Content#Upload_a_file

Comment: I am working on a response. You will need to implement the whitelist plugin. You likely have an incorrect setting. The default (example) configuration does  not work for QuickBlox or firebase (which i use).

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 Ok thanks Jesse,I will be waiting for your response

Comment: Hi Gurtej Singh, can you post the solution for this. I need it urgently. Thanks in advance.